# Is there a way to add counting up numbers to the end of duplicate data in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I am working with a lot of ISBN's for a library system for my work. We have a few duplicate books and I am looking for a way to have excel add .0 .1 .2 etc. for each duplicate. I am wondering if this is possible and if so how do I do it? I have tried to use concatenate within an if that uses counta to determine if it has shown up yet. I need to know what to do. I would prefer not hard code them in.[image: Data]

Comment: Can you share the formula you used? Presumably it should be COUNTIF.

Comment: There are several ways to do this; one fairly simple approach would be to use countif on a sorted range to concatenate.  With your above data, the output could be in Column G such that `G2=F2&"."&countif($F$1:F1,F2)`, so every first ID starts with ".0".  This formula can be filled down the column.  There are more robust options, not requiring sorting, but as stated this is fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following data set to demonstrate my solution:

[image: Example Data Set]

In cell `A2`, enter the following formula and drag it down:

```
=LEFT($B2,4)&RIGHT($F2,4)&IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$F$9,$F2)>1,"."&(COUNTIF($F$2:$F2,$F2)-1),"")
```

> There are three parts of this formula, first part is `LEFT($B2,4)` which extracts the first four letters of the subject code; second part is `RIGHT($F2,4)` which extracts the last four digits from the ISBN code;
>
> third part is `IF(COUNTIF($F$2:$F$9,$F2)>1,"."&(COUNTIF($F$2:$F2,$F2)-1),"")` which is firstly using **COUNTIF** to find out if there is duplicated ISBN code, if so, use `"."&(COUNTIF($F$2:$F2,$F2)-1)` to return the `.0`, `.1`, `.2` etc. as desired, if there is duplicated ISBN code, return a blank or `""`.

[image: Solution]

Let me know if you have any question. Cheers :)